# Yathesis Class. logo size on cover issue

Tags: yathesis

In the class Yathesis, how to change the size of the logo at the top of the cover page? One of the two logo appears much smaller than the second one. I tried to change to logo size directement from the .jpg files I was saving, but it is not changing anything.
Is there a way to improve the symmetry here?

Many thanks for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The class Yathesis will equalize the height of the logos. You can change the height of particular logo with `logoheight` as in `\institute[logoheight=1cm, logo=images/ulco]{ULCO}`

In this example the logos are in the sub-directory `images`. They have very different heights, as it can be seen, but they appear top and bottom aligned in the title page.

[image: c]

**ComUE.jpg**  (140x119)

[image: cue]

**Institut.jpg** (688x190)

[image: ins]

**CoInstitut.jpg**  (942x264)

[image: coin]

Download the three images in a sub directory `images` of your working directory, change their names and try this code.

```
\documentclass{yathesis}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{kpfonts}

\begin{document}

\author[aa@zygo.fr]{Alphonse}{Allais}\title[Laugh’s Chaos]{Le chaos du rire}
\subtitle[Chaos’ Laugh]{Le rire du chaos}
\academicfield[Mathematics]{Mathématiques}
\speciality[Dynamical systems]{Systèmes dynamiques}
\date{15}{8}{2021}
\submissiondate{1}{10}{2020}
\subject[Chaotic Laugh]{Rire chaotique}
\doctoralschool[url=http://edspi.univ-lille1.fr/]{ED Régionale SPI 72}

\comue[logo=images/ComUE,url=]{ComUE Lille Nord de France} % <<<<<<<<<<<<<<

\institute[logo=images/Institut,url=]{ULCO}% <<<<<<<<<<<<<<

\coinstitute[logo=images/CoInstitut]{Université de Paris~13}% <<<<<<<<<<<<<<

\laboratory[
logo=,
telephone=,
fax=,
email=,
url=
]{{LMPA Joseph Liouville}}{%
  \\
  \\
  \\
  \\
  \\
  }


\maketitle

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot!! It works fine with the logoheight option. The rest of the code was correct but the logos was appearing too small.